# Make Link expire after X minutes

Tags: php, email

Okay I am sending an activation email link to user's email. My Activation  link is working perfect I wants to make that link expire after X minutes.
Here is my code:

```
$base_url='http://172.16.0.60/WebServices/';
$activation=md5($email.time());
email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = 'Activate Your Account';
        $mail->Body    = 'Hi, <br/> <br/> We need to make sure you are human. Please verify your email and get started using your Website account. <br/> <br/> <a href="'.$base_url.'activation/'.$activation.'">'.$base_url.'activation/'.$activation.'</a>';
```

Now my
    .htaccess file

```
 RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^activation/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ activation.php?code=$1
    RewriteRule ^activation/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ activation.php?code=$1
```

Now how can I make my link expire? I dont have timestamp field in my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got my answer using this simply,
Send a timestamp in link and on other end while accepting the link I have to check the time with current time stamp.

```
$base_url='http://172.16.0.60/WebServices/';
$activation=md5($email.time());
$time = time();
email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = 'Activate Your Account';
        $mail->Body    = 'Hi, <br/> <br/> We need to make sure you are human. Please verify your email and get started using your Website account. <br/> <br/> <a href="'.$base_url.'activation/'.$activation.'">'.$base_url.'activation/'.$activation.$time.'</a>';
```

While when user clicks on link, following code will check the expiration of link.

```
$u_time = $this->input->get('time'); // fetching time variable from URL
$u_time = md5($u_time);
$cur_time = time(); //fetching current time to check with GET variable's time
if ($cur_time - $u_time < 10800) 
{
 // link is not expired
}
else
{
 // link has been expired
}
```

Comment: As a receiver of your mail I can just update the time and make the link working again.

Comment: It's not going to work. First of all, you check the time from the url (which is md5), and check it with `time()` which is not md5. so you're basically checking `md5(time) - time() < 10800`

Comment: Okk my mistake at the time of comparision I will convert it to md5. Edited!

Comment: I'm sorry to burst your bubble, but you can't compare 2 md5 hashes. You're basically checking `randomstring - randomstring < 10800`. Please add a time field to your database.

Answer (score 5):

> I dont have timestamp field in my database.

Then **add** one.

Add a field to record when the link was generated and you can then instantly check against that time when they visit. There is no need to waste time trying to think of hacks when you can simply adjust your setup accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata"); // set time_zone according to your location
$expire_date = "2019-03-26 14:45:00"; // time that you want the link to expire 
echo $now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // your current time.

if ($now>$expire_date) {

    echo " Your link is expired";
}
else
{
   echo " link is still alive";
}
```

you can find your time_zone [here](http://www.timezoneconverter.com/cgi-bin/findzone.tzc)

Hope this helps:)